# How to unzip many .gz files to one same file?

Tags: gzip

I have a folder which contains a lot of .gz files, each of them contains los as text.

It's too troublesome to unzip and look through them one by one. So I'm wondering is there any command to unzip content of mutiple .gz files to a same file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the command you want probably:

> cat *.gz | gzip -dc - | grep los

First the *cat *.gz* sends all the zipped files to stdout.
Using *gzip* the -d switch decompresses and -c sends output to stdout. The "-" allows input to come from stdin rather than through files.
Then this output can be piped to whatever program you want.

If you want to know the specifically each file that has matches you can do this too:

> for f in *.gz
>     do echo $f: ;
>     gzip -dc $f | grep los ;
>   done